# GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndVector3Axis wrongly handles positive angle as clockwise

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, glkit

I am using GLKit quaternion to rotate a unit vector by 90 degrees around z-axis.
Here is my code:

```
let q = GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndVector3Axis(Float(M_PI_2), GLKVector3Make(0,0,-1))
let result = GLKQuaternionRotateVector3(q, GLKVector3Make(1,0,0))
```

But the result shows the vector (0, -1, 0) where I expected (0, 1, 0). 
According to the GLKit Framework Reference, the input angle argument for GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndVector3Axis is explained :

> radians : The angle of the rotation in radians (a positive angle is counterclockwise).

So I expected my code rotates x-y plane by 90 degrees counterclockwise where I am looking down the x-y plane from the position where z > 0. But actually the result showed the plane was rotated clockwise.

Can someone point out what I understand wrongly?